# Python random number game, response different based on closeness to random number

Tags: python, random

Attempting to generate different responses based on closeness of guess to the randomly generated number. Commented out sections are my attempts at generating a different response for a guess that is within 10 numbers of the random number.

```
import random

while True:

    number = random.randint(1,1000)
    guess = 0
    tries = 0

    while guess != number:
        guess = input('Please enter your guess, number must be between 0 and 1000: ')
        tries += 1
    if guess < number:
        if number - 10 <= guess:
            print('Getting warm but still too low!')
        print('Too Low!')
    elif guess > number:
        if number + 10 >= guess:
            print('Getting warm but still too high!')
        print('Too High!')
    print("Great Guess! The number was %i and you guessed it in %s tries!") % (number, tries)
    again = raw_input("Enter 'y' or 'n' to select to play again: ")
    if again == 'n':
        break
```

Yields the below output when within the specified range of the randomly generated number.

```
Please enter your guess, number must be between 0 and 1000: 256
Getting warm but still too low!
Too Low!
Please enter your guess, number must be between 0 and 1000: 257
Great Guess! The number was 257 and you guessed it in 13 tries!
```

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem you're running into?

Comment: The issue I am encountering is that the message does not change based on how close the guess is. Ultimately  if the guess is within 10 numbers of the random number, the printed context should report that they are getting warmer.

Comment: So with if statements, the system will check each condition going down the list, one by one. That means that, in your case, if you have a range from too low -> too high, your conditions should be ordered in that same way. For example, the first condition `guess < number` is true regardless if `guess` is close to `number` or not. Which means that it doesn't ever get a chance to check `number - 10 <= guess`

Comment: I've modified the conditions so that the "getting warmer" condition is within the original. This seems to do the trick, with one more tiny issue remaining however. While it does print out that the guess is within 10 numbers now, it will also print out that it is either too low or too high as well. Is there a better way to set this condition so that, if the guess is within the set proximity, the general message of too high or too low is not printed?

Comment: `if (number - 10) <= guess or (number + 10) >= guess`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to indentation, as a beginner you should see how basic nested loop work. The code after indentation will yield the correct result. I have added an additional else to handle print "Too Low" and "Too High"

```
import random

while True:

    number = random.randint(1,1000)
    guess = 0
    tries = 0

    while guess != number:
         guess = input('Please enter your guess, number must be between 0 and 1000: ')
         tries += 1
         if guess < number:
             if number - 10 <= guess:
                 print('Getting warm but still too low!')
             else:
                 print('Too Low!')
         elif guess > number:
             if number + 10 >= guess:
                 print('Getting warm but still too high!')
             else:
                 print('Too High!')
        else:
            print("Great Guess! The number was %i and you guessed it in %s tries!") % (number, tries)

    again = raw_input("Enter 'y' or 'n' to select to play again: ")
    if again == 'n':
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the condition of the first 'if clause' is met first, the others condition will be ignored. You could re-arrange the if clause to show the message as you want:

```
    if number - 10 <= guess:
        print('Getting warm but still too low!')
    elif guess < number:
        print('Too Low!') 
    elif number + 10 >= guess:
        print('Getting warm but still too high!')
    elif guess > number:
        print('Too High!')
```